# Forge design automation: Error missing output file

Tags: forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am using design automation to get information about **DWG file**.
On design automation I output a file ***result.json***, and my server has a callback to get that file.
But I got 1 error from design automation:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gIN0J.png).

This is my Parameters:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFeq9.png)

And this is my code for save file on Design automation: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izi5P.png)

I also tried Forge's example [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation), but the result is not good

This is my work-item id: cf4c8a53727942c894fd367d573a78e4

Comment: The command `UpdateParam` is not recognized , I suspect the bundle is not uploaded correctly.
Can you run [Get Bundle](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/design-automation/v3/reference/http/appbundles-id-GET)
Please do share your workitem Id.

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala this is my workitem id: cf4c8a53727942c894fd367d573a78e4

Comment: Sorry, can you please share workitem report.

Comment: @MadhukarMoogala I have updated the work item report in the comments below

Comment: Thanks for sharing workitem report I just tried the sample, it works for me.
https://controlc.com/7b791415
Did you call Get Bundle API ? or using different bundle then listed here https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/tree/master/forgesample/wwwroot/bundles

Comment: You need to share your project, I'm interested to know the activity and bundle code. I can see the command UpdateParam is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Answer if anyone got this error:
If you follow this demo: [Learn Design Automation](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation)

You need to pay attention to your option "**script**" of dll command in  **EngineAttributes()** function: [here](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/learn.forge.designautomation/blob/master/forgesample/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs#:%7E:text=dwg%22%2C-,script,-%3D%20%22UpdateParam)